# Z3 ast_to_string() API with Subtraction

Tags: z3

The problem is pretty simple.
I assert following statement in Z3 using the C API interface.

```
(assert(>= (xA 1) (- (yB 0) period))))
```

Now Sometimes, I need to check what kind of assertions have been fed and the result in the SatSolver. I do this, by generating a text file by using ast_to_string() API. This API returns me above statement as -

```
(assert(>= (xA 1) (+ (yB 0) (* -1 period))))
```

When I feed this file to the Sat Solver it complains me with the error -

> (error "ERROR: line 150 column 56: could not locate id  -1.")

So then, I have to manually fix all -1 in the code and run the sat solver.
Is there any other way where I can avoid this?

Comment: What do you mean by the SatSolver? Why do need to go through a text file? Can't just invoke it from the API as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to set:

```
Z3_set_ast_print_mode(ctx,Z3_PRINT_SMTLIB2_COMPLIANT);
```

before using `ast_to_string()` in order that that output formulas comply with SMTLIB 2.0 format.

Comment: Doesn't really solve the problem. For example I get following in the output -
`(assert(let ((?x28 (xA 1))) (>= ?x28 0)))`
so it eventually kills the benefit of printing it to a file.

Comment: The thing is that whether the output is parsable by Z3 or not. At last, SMTLIB is a machine-readable format, not a human-readable format.